# "Column" object not callable when using when,endsWith & Regex_replace

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a simple set of address data as below; simply trying to replace street names with Abbreviations:

```
14851 Jeffrey Rd
43421 Margarita St
110 South Ave
```

in my pyspark program I am simply using a regexp replace the abbreviations with full name like Road, Street,etc.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract
address = [(1,"14851 Jeffrey Rd","DE"),(2,"43421 Margarita St","NY"),(3,"13111 Siemon 
Ave","CA"),(4,"110 South Ave","FL")]
df= spark.createDataFrame(name,["id","address","state"])
df.withColumn("address",
when(col("address").endsWith("Rd"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"Rd","Road"))
.when(col("address").endsWith("St"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"St","Street"))
.when(col("address").endsWith("Ave"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"Ave","Avenue"))
.otherwise("address"))
.show(false)
```

I tried replacing "col("address") with df.address or $"address" but I keep getting same error.

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

P.S running on Spark 3.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `endswith`, not `endsWith`,Note the case and the last `show` function.

```
df.withColumn("address",
              when(col("address").endswith("Rd"), regexp_replace(col("address"), "Rd", "Road"))
              .when(col("address").endswith("St"), regexp_replace(col("address"), "St", "Street"))
              .when(col("address").endswith("Ave"), regexp_replace(col("address"), "Ave", "Avenue"))
              .otherwise("address")) \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: interesting; I was reading through sparkbyexample.com and they had it as "endsWith" ; even spark 2.0 book is laid out like that!...
 https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-filter-startswith-endswith-examples/

Answer (score 0):

Change `endsWith` function to all lowercase **`endswith`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("address",
when(col("address").endswith("Rd"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"Rd","Road"))\
.when(col("address").endswith("St"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"St","Street"))\
.when(col("address").endswith("Ave"),regexp_replace(col("address"),"Ave","Avenue"))\
.otherwise(col("address")))\
.show(10,False)
#+---+----------------------+-----+
#|id |address               |state|
#+---+----------------------+-----+
#|1  |14851 Jeffrey Road    |DE   |
#|2  |43421 Margarita Street|NY   |
#|3  |13111 Siemon Avenue   |CA   |
#|4  |110 South Avenue      |FL   |
#+---+----------------------+-----+
```

Comment: yes it seems that that is the correct syntax but as I was reading through sparkbyexample.com and they had it as "endsWith" ; even spark 2.0 book is laid out like that!...

https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-filter-startswith-endswith-examples/